# Select top 1 column value in the group by clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, distinct

I am joining two tables and my query contains the group by clause. There is one column in the join table which I want to show in the result but doesn't want it to be part of group by because values are different in column values. I just want to show any top value of that column.

I tried to use Distinct and Top 1 and others but nothing works for me.

```
SELECT t1.Code, t2.Details, t2.FineDate ,Sum(t1.Amount) from Emp_Actions t1 
INNER JOIN Emp_Fines  ON  t1.Code =  t2.Code 
where (t1.Code = "MYParameter" or @MyParameter = "" )
group by t1.Code,t2.Details,t2.FineDate
```

Please note that I am using `StoredProcedure` and code be specific or all. My actual query is too big and I just made a sample to elaborate my issue. I need `Top 1` FineDate, I don't want it to part of group by however I want to show it.

Comment: Without seeing the whole query I can suggest MAX(col) or MIN(col), where col is the column that you don't want to group on.

Comment: Have you already tried to enclose the column you don't want in the group with STRING_AGG()?

Comment: well, you can't use double quotes as a string delimiter in tsql unless you change a **very important** setting that can cause problems elsewhere. So stop using double quotes generally.

Comment: @EzLo `first_value` (and `last_value`) was introduced as early as 2012... Documentation for many functions seems to be lacking the starting from information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MIN()` or `MAX()`:

```
select t1.Code, t2.Details, t2.FineDate, Sum(t1.Amount),
       max(<your column here>) as column+name
from Emp_Actions t1 join
     Emp_Fines  
     on  t1.Code = t2.Code 
where (t1.Code = "MYParameter" or @MyParameter = "" )
group by t1.Code, t2.Details, t2.FineDate
```

Comment: `MIN()` worked perfectly. `MAX()' doesn't load data sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get only one value, is using MAX(col) or MIN(col) in your SELECT statement, where col is the column that you don't want to group on. One advantage is that you get somewhat consistent values (first or last in order).

SELECT t1.Code, t2.Details, t2.FineDate, **MAX(col) my_col**, Sum(t1.Amount) from Emp_Actions t1

Also, there are more advanced analytical window functions (first_value for example), if you want to go that way, to have more control over which value is chosen, also depending on other column values.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/analytic-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

You can use use subquery for required result.

I am giving you a sample code :

```
Select
t1.Code, t2.Details, t2.FineDate,Sum(t1.Amount) 
,(select top 1 a.ColA from Emp_Fines a where a.Code = t1.Code order by ColOfSort Asc/Desc) as RequiredColumn
from Emp_Actions t1 
INNER JOIN Emp_Fines t2 ON  t1.Code =  t2.Code 
where (t1.Code = "MYParameter" or @MyParameter = "" )
group by t1.Code,t2.Details,t2.FineDate
```

Where RequiredColumn is the column that you wants in the result but don't want to use in group by